# Breeze querying local cache with EF and Web API

Tags: breeze

Problem

I have a view with 6 drop downs. Each of which is being populated by a Web API call. I want 
to use breeze to run the query locally once it has populated from the remote server

The code runs fine when the data call is against the server. The issue is when trying to query the local cache. I never get any results returned.  Is my approach flawed or am I doing something wrong ?

SERVER SIDE

**View model**

```
class genericDropDown()
{
public int value{get;set;}
public string option{get;set;}

}
```

**The WebAPI [A single sample method]**

```
  [HttpGet]
        // GET api/<controller>
        public object GetSomeVals()
        {

            return _context.getClinician();


        }
```

**The Repository [A single sample method]**

```
public IEnumerable<genericDropDown> getDropDownVal()
{
     return context.somemodel(a=>new{a.id,a.firstname,a.lastname}).ToList().
                    Select(x => new GenericDropDown 
       { value = x.id, option = x.firstname+ " " + x.lastname});}

}
```

CLIENT SIDE

**Datacontext.js**

```
   var _manager = new breeze.EntityManager("EndPoint");

//Being called from my view model

    var getDropDownBindings = function(KO1, KO2) {

//First add the entity to the local metadatastore then populate the entity

        $.when(
            addDD('clinicianDropDown', webAPIMethod),
            getData(KO1, webAPIMethod, null, 'clinicianDropDown'),

            addDD('docTypeDropDown', webAPIMethod);
             getData(KO2, webAPIMethod, null, 'docTypeDropDown'),

        ).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);


        function querySucceeded(data) {
            logger.log('Got drop down vals', "", 'dataContext', true);
        }

    };


//Add the entity to local store. First param is typename and second is 
resource name (Web API method)

    var addDD = function(shortName,resName) {

        _manager.metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: shortName,
            namespace: "Namespace",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            defaultResourceName:resName,
            dataProperties: {
                value: { dataType: DataType.Int32, 
                 isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                option: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: false }
            }
        });
        return _manager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(shortName, null, null);

    };

//Get the data

    var getData = function(observableArray, dataEndPoint, parameters, mapto) {
        if (observableArray != null)
            observableArray([]);

    //TO DO: Incorporate logic for server or local call depending on
// whether this method is accessed for the first time

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(dataEndPoint);
        if (mapto != null && mapto != "")
            query = query.toType(mapto);

        if (parameters != null)
            query = query.withParameters(parameters);

//This approach doesnt work on local querying as Jquery complains 
//there is no 'then' method. Not sure how to implement promises 
//when querying locally

  /*     return _manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);


        function querySucceeded(data) {
            if (observableArray != null)
                observableArray(data.results);


        }
*/


//The array length from this query is always 0 
var data = _manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
  observableArray(data.results);
return;


    };

//Generic error handler

function queryFailed(error) {

        logger.log(error.message, null, 'dataContext', true);
    }
```

**viewmodel.js**

```
//In Durandal's activate method populate the observable arrays

dataContext.getDropDownBindings (KO1,KO2);
```

Viewmodel.html

```
<select class="dropdown" data-bind="options: KO1, optionsText: 'option', value: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Clinicians'"></select>

<select class="dropdown" data-bind="options: KO2 optionsText: 'option', value: 'value', optionsCaption: 'Document Types'"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only execute local queries against types that are described by metadata.

Without more information I can't be sure, but my guess is that your *GetSomeVals* method is not returning 'entities' but just loose data.  In other words, the types of objects returned from the *GetSomeVals* method must be entities (or contain entities within a projection) in order for breeze to be able to perform a local query.  This is because Breeze knows how to cache and query entities but has no ideas how to cache 'arbitrary' query results.

Note that you can return an anonymous type containing entities of different types from the server, (in order to populate mostly static small datasets), but the individual items must be 'entities'. In this case, Breeze will take apart the anon result and pick out any entities to include in the EntityManager cache.

Per you question of how to perform an local query with promises, use the *FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache* with the *using* method.

i.e. this query

```
 var results = em.executeQueryLocally(query)
```

can also be expressed as:

```
 query = query.using(FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache);
 return em.executeQuery(query).then(data) {
   var results = data.results;

 }
```

The local query is still executed synchonously but is made to look async.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay. Could I get you to explain a bit more.So when you say the query has to return entities, it has to return the complete entities with every property ? For example lets say I have a user entity with 10 fields and a related city and country entity . To get my users name and address my query will need to return the user and user.city and user.country for breeze to be able to query the cache ? So the JSON data will contain all user fields and all related city and country fields ?

Comment: Modified the repository query to return entitites .. it now reads return context.MainEntity.Includes("RelatedEntities")..Can see results in JSON being returned. The datacontext code has been changed to use the fetchstrategy and the query.ToType mapping has been removed. Local querying still returns 0 results when querying the cache.

Comment: Ok heres what was happening..A call is happening to addDD which registers a short name, resource name and namespace. So even if a query.ToType is not being called when the query is executed against the breeze recognises the resource name and tries to use the namespace to find the entity in the cache and fails but does not throw any error. I removed the function which was registering the new EntityType with the metadata store and its all good now.